# Regarding the questions where it is asked whether the proofs given by the user is correct or not

Tags: discussion, solution-verification

I have seen instances of people asking whether their proofs are correct or not. In such cases, the answers are often given in the comments section because the actual proof of the question has not been asked by the user.

Shouldn't there be some dedicated way to handled such questions, because after all these kinds of questions end up with no answers in the answer box?

What kind of feature (if any) could help us to deal with such questions effectively?

Comment: If you browse the questions tagged ([meta-tag:solution-verification]) a bit, you might find some related questions. For example, this one seems related to your post, [How to answer proof-verification questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions)

Comment: The answer is fine but it would be better if a new feature for this is incorporated in the website which will encourage the users to answer accordingly.

Comment: What specifically do you propose? If you just want to discuss what could be done, please do not tag feature-request.

Comment: I was just giving a suggestion

Comment: Okay. I edited the question a bit to make it more a call for discussion.